# how can I emulate rpi image with QEMU

Tags: yocto, qemu

I am trying to emulate a raspberry pi3-64 (yocto build image) with QEMU and I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/poky/scripts/runqemu", line 1567, in main
    config.setup_final()
  File "/home/ubuntu/poky/scripts/runqemu", line 1414, in setup_final
    self.setup_serial()
  File "/home/ubuntu/poky/scripts/runqemu", line 1349, in setup_serial
    self.kernel_cmdline_script += ' console=%s' %entry.split(';')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
runqemu - INFO - Cleaning up
Set 'tap0' nonpersistent
```

ps : I am using the run qemu poky provides runqemu raspberrypi3-64 nographic
when I use the runqemu raspberrypi3-64  I get this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xj8R.png)

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are running yocto, the guest starts, prints some data on the screen (screenshor provided), then runqemu script fails with the provided error and qemu stops working?

Comment: no, I am emulating an rpi image on qemu with runqemu raspberrypi3-64 nographic I get the error I pasted in the script when I use runqemu raspberrypi3-64 I get the error in the pic (runqemu works with qemu within poky)